# Handle a lot of data in symfony select form

Tags: php, symfony

I have a 2 entities "Localization" and "Job" in my "Job" edit view I have to assign many `Localizations` but whenever I load edit view of my form pages takes ages to load because of massive `Localizations` amount. I decided that I should load them dynamically but when I set

```
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er): QueryBuilder {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('l')
           ->setMaxResults(100);
 },
```

`EntityType:class` in form for max results ex. 100 it loads them and quickly displays edit form. In edit form I created select2 widget to load via ajax rest of the localizations BUT. When I choose one of NOT loaded initialy localization but loaded via ajax for example 200th record and try to save form I get error saying "This value is not valid" like `EntityType:class` field have mapped 100 possible answears and validate my 200th record as not valid.

How can I set up this properly? Can You recommend some bundle that do this magic out of the box?
I'm using symfony 5.4 and I creating dashboard without bundles like EasyAdmin/Sonata - plain symfony

Comment: Have a look at [`Alsatian67/FormBundle`](https://github.com/Alsatian67/FormBundle) which has an auto-complete AJAX field that has examples using Select2.

Comment: Use ux autocomplete - https://symfony.com/bundles/ux-autocomplete/current/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out without extra bundles. I will post my solution for people with similar problem as mine for future reference

```
in: src/Form/JobFormType

class JobFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      //Field with a LOT of options
      $localizationsFieldFunction = $this->getLocalizationsFieldFunction();
      $builder->add('someField', TextType:class,[..args])
              ->add('association', EntityType:class,[...args])
      ;

      $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $localizationsFieldFunction)
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, $localizationsFieldFunction)
    }

    private function getLocalizationsFieldFunction(   )
    {
        return function (FormEvent $event){
            $form = $event->getForm();

            /** @var Job $data */
            $data = $event->getData();
            $localizationIds = [];
            //PRE_SET_DATA form event gets me Job entity
            if ($data instanceof Job){
                $localizations = $data->getLocalization();
                $localizationIds = array_map(function (JobLocalization $localization){
                    return $localization->getId();
                },$localizations->getValues());
            }
            // PRE_SUBMIT form event gets me an array of sent ids
            else if (is_array($data) && isset( $data['localization'] )){
                $localizationIds = $data['localization'];
            }

            $form->add('localization', EntityType::class,[
                'class' => JobLocalization::class,
                'label'=>'Localization',
                'expanded' => false,
                'multiple' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'attr'=>[
                    'class'=>'select2localizations'
                ],
                'query_builder' => function (JobLocalizationRepository $repository) use ($localizationIds) {
                    return $repository->createQueryBuilder('localizations')
                        ->where('localizations.id IN (:localizationIds)')
                        ->setParameter('localizationIds', $localizationIds);
                }
            ]);
        };
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'class' => Job::class,
            'data_class' => Job::class,
            'validation_groups' => false,
            'csrf_protection'=>true,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Example above sets selected localizations in rendered form.

```
In assets/app.js

        $('.select2localizations').select2({
            allowClear: false,
            maximumSelectionLength: 3,
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            closeOnSelect:false,
            placeholder: 'Start typing for localization',
            ajax: {
                url: endpoint_to_search_localization_action,
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term,
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
                    return {
                        results: data.items
                    };
                }
            }
        });
```

And this example allows me to make requests to my controller that search for localization.